# rxjs Subject to move data between 3 components

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to move data between 3 Angular components using this design pattern:

[image: img]

**myservice.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  myString = new Subject<string>();
  myString$ = this.myString.asObservable();

  setMyString(data: string) {
        console.log("service component is calling next");
        this.myString.next(data);
  }
}
```

**informations.component.ts**

```
informations.component.ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './myservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'informations',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: './informations.component.html'
})

export class InformationsComponent implements OnInit {
  aString = '';

  constructor(public myservice: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
        console.log("subscribing");
        this.myservice.myString.subscribe({
            next: (v) => console.log(`observer: ${v}`)
        });
  }
}
```

**table.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './myservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'table',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: './table.component.html'
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public myservice: MyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("table component is calling setMyString");
        this.myservice.setMyString("MY STRING HERE!");
  }

}
```

The problem here is that all 3 console.log are getting called in this order:

1. "table component is calling setMyString"
2. "service component is calling next"
3. "subscribing"

but not the one in the table component. This never gets called:

```
    this.myservice.myString.subscribe({
        next: (v) => console.log(`observer: ${v}`)
    });
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is for the informations component to get notified whenever `myString` changes (and I want table to be doing that): is this the right way? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `Subject` with `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan the new rxjs best practices are that BehaviorSubject is appropriate when a default value should exist. Otherwise, prefer ReplaySubect(1) as it doesn't force a default value that may not make sense

Comment: @bryan60 - Interesting. I remember that we both made opposite suggestions in another recent post... :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan I was using behavior subjects for this purpose forever, but so often I had to put in nonsense null defaults where there shouldn't be one and add like filter(v => !!v)... usin ReplaySubject(1) is so much cleaner in those cases... maybe that post converted me haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this probably just a timing problem where info component sends the data before table component exists and can subscribe to it. use a ReplaySubject instead

```
myString = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
```

Comment: You're right about the order. The problem here is that I'm calling setMyString before subscribing. I've tried calling setMyString from another function and the subscription works! Do you think with ReplaySubject I can provide a default value from the table component? I'm trying right now...

Comment: if you want a default value, then BehaviorSubject is the way to go as it accepts a default value as an argument

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the Observable `myString$`, not the Subject `myString`

```
this.myservice.myString$.subscribe((v) => console.log(`observer: ${v}`));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've tried it but nothing changes. The console.log inside of the subscribe still doesn't get called.

Comment: My bad, I saw this and didn't think to check the rest of the code. You are using a subscription as a promise. I made an update to show to proper way to use it.